# How to log both HTTP and HTTPS requests to the same file

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, logging, mod-ssl

Using recent Apache on Linux.

It's inconvenient to have the two different kinds of requests sent to two different log files since I like to watch the log file scroll by live via the shell.  I also use `less` a lot.

Also, is there a reason why logging should not be combined?

Comment: tail can be used on multiple log files "tail -f /var/log/file1 /var/log/file2" or with a wildcard "tail -f /var/log/apache/*.log". Take a look at the apache docs on log for making changes to the loggin conf: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  But, I also use `less` a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Change your log line in your config file to have the same log file. There are no reasons that I ever found.

I.e.:

CustomLog logs/access_log common

in both config file.